# Excel Pivot Chart - Top Ten, Hide One Column

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot chart in Excel that I have created using the value filter for "Top 10". The biggest category right now is "Unknown" and everyone using it understands this. So really, I want to see the top ten other than this "unknown" column. How can I hide the data for unknown while keeping the dynamic top ten? (I thought maybe doing the top 11 and hiding that column, but I cant sort out how to hide it...) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution- super simple:

1. Right-click a cell in the pivot table, and click PivotTable Options.
2. Click the Totals & Filters tab
3. Under Filters, add a check mark to ‘Allow multiple filters per field.’
4. Click OK

Now I can deselect "Unknown" from the list, while also including the value filter for top ten.

Answer (score 0):

First do top 11, then rightclick on "Unknown", on context menu filter > exclude selected (my Excel is in spanish so it could be worded slightly different)

Notice that this will also remove the values for "Unknown" from your grand total sum.